# No OQGraph in my MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, oqgraph

I've just installed MariaDB on my Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, as explained [in this blog](http://nick125.com/2010/08/mariadb-on-ubuntu-server-and-wordpress/):
Unfortunately, there is no OQGraph engine in it.

I must admit I'm a little bit confused between MariaDB, OurDelta, OpenQuery... I don't know who is doing what, but I would like to have OQGraph engine on my MariaDB.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the plugin first.
Run the following sql:

```
install plugin oqgraph soname 'ha_oqgraph.so';
```

After that the engine should be visible under SHOW ENGINES.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! It worked with my MariaDB 5.2 installation on Ubuntu 10.10 (For people who might need it, here is the link I used to install MariaDB : http://kb.askmonty.org/v/installing-mariadb-deb-files)

Answer (score 0):

OQGraph storage engine is included in MariaDB 5.2.1 Beta. Being a Beta release, go to the [MariaDB download page](http://askmonty.org/wiki/MariaDB:Download:MariaDB_5.2.1-beta) and get it from there. OpenQuery is the developers behind OQGraph storage Engine and they also offer tech support on MySQL and MariaDB. MariaDB is a RDB Management System which uses Aria as the default storage Engine and maintained by [Monty Program AB](http://askmonty.org/).

Comment: I have successfully installed MariaDB 5.2.1 Beta, and when I do SHOW ENGINES; there is no OQGraph... only Blackhole, MRG_MyISAM, Federated, Maria, CSV, Memory, Archive, MyIsam, InnoDB, and PBXT.

So it doesn't work neither... any other suggestion?