# MariaDB: How to install OQGRAPH as DB Engine on Arch Linux

Tags: database, mariadb, archlinux, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is it possible to install OQGRAPH for MariaDB on Arch Linux? If so, how?

Here are my currently installed engines:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                                          | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables                                        | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MyISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | Stores tables as CSV files                                                                       | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears)                                   | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | Non-transactional engine with good performance and small data footprint                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | gzip-compresses tables for a low storage footprint                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| Aria               | YES     | Crash-safe tables with MyISAM heritage                                                           | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Percona-XtraDB, Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| SEQUENCE           | YES     | Generated tables filled with sequential values                                                   | YES          | NO   | YES        |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Following instructions I found to install oqgraph, here are my results:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> install plugin oqgraph soname 'ha_oqgraph.so';

ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_oqgraph.so' (errno: 2, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

That file is not present:

```
ls /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_oqgraph.so
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_oqgraph.so': No such file or directory
```

Both of these return no results:

```
pacman -Ss oqgraph
pacman -Ss "open query graph"
```

Related pages:

OQGraph is not mentioned on the Arch Wiki page:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL

[No OQGraph in my MariaDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589895/no-oqgraph-in-my-mariadb)
The accepted solution doesn't work for me.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-oqgraph/
The page doesn't provide an Arch Linux solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work-around, not an ideal solution. However, it works.

Match the version of downloaded libraries with the version of MariaDB you have installed.

Download `libJudy.so.1`. I did not find libJudy in the Arch repos. **UPDATE**: from Kevin Andrews (see comment):

> libJudy is now in the community repo so a sudo pacman -S community/judy is enough.

Leaving my old steps in case they are helpful to anybody. Else jump to **Next** below.

*Previously*, I used http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/judy/libjudydebian1_1.0.5-5_amd64.deb. Then followed these steps to install the lib.

```
extract libJudy.so.1.0.3
cd /lib
sudo mv libJudy.so.1.0.3 .
sudo ln -s libJudy.so.1.0.3 libJudy.so.1
sudo chmod 644 libJudy.so.1.0.3
```

**Next** you need `ha_oqgraph.so`. I downloaded the full official tarball of [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/interstitial/mariadb-10.1.37/bintar-linux-x86_64/mariadb-10.1.37-linux-x86_64.tar.gz/from/http%3A//mirrors.syringanetworks.net/mariadb/) to obtain that file, matching the version with the version of MariaDB installed from the Arch repos.

```
extract ha_oqgraph.so
sudo mv ha_oqgraph.so /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_oqgraph.so
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_oqgraph.so
```

log into MariaDB as root and run:

```
MariaDB > install plugin oqgraph soname 'ha_oqgraph.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

then run this to confirm the OQGRAPH was installed:

```
MariaDB > show engines;
```

Here's my result:

```
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                                          | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables                                        | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MyISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | Stores tables as CSV files                                                                       | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears)                                   | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | Non-transactional engine with good performance and small data footprint                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | gzip-compresses tables for a low storage footprint                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| Aria               | YES     | Crash-safe tables with MyISAM heritage                                                           | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Percona-XtraDB, Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| OQGRAPH            | YES     | Open Query Graph Computation Engine (http://openquery.com/graph)                                 | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| SEQUENCE           | YES     | Generated tables filled with sequential values                                                   | YES          | NO   | YES        |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
11 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: libJudy is now in the community repo so a `sudo pacman -S community/judy` is enough. Following the rest of your guide worked perfectly making sure to match up the MariaDB versions.